# Como conectarse a Internet con VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Esta es mi configuración inicial de red.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero falla al querer conectarme a Internet

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparto la solución que me funciono

PASO 1

abrir la terminal de centos 7

PASO 2

Copiar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PASO 3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**REFERENCIA**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZayzoEAT3A

Comment: Hola @DANIELHS, agradezco que hayas compartido la solución con la que has resuelto tu problema. Te he editado la pregunta ya que en este sitio no utilizamos la palabra "Resuelto" ni similares en la pregunta para indicar que se ha resuelto la duda en cuestión, si no que hay un tick a la izquierda de cada una de las respuestas que puedes marcar para indicar que es la respuesta aceptada y con ello se sabrá que es la respuesta que te ha ayudado a solucionar tu error. Creo que si es una respuesta la pregunta de uno mismo hay un mínimo de dos días para poder aceptarla. Un saludo :)

Comment: genial, gracias por tu comentario